# slurm request entire node

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I am a using a HPC which uses `slurm 20.11.7`.
I try to execute a script which seems to use all available cores, even if I have not reserved all cores on the node. This might cause problems for other users. So my idea was that it is best if I am the only user that is currently running operations on that node, however, I was not able to find a option which allows this.

I would greatly appreciate if somebody could tell me if there is a submission option, which requests all resources of a node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `--exclusive` flag with `sbatch`.

From `sbatch` man page:

```
--exclusive[=user|mcs]
       The  job  allocation  can  not  share nodes with other running jobs (or just other users with the "=user" option or with the "=mcs" option).  The default shared/exclusive behavior depends on system configuration and the partition's
       OverSubscribe option takes precedence over the job's option.
```